# Unable to pass access_token to endpoint in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, access-token, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from an API which requires `access_token`. There is another API for fetching `access_token`. So, I am first trying to fetch acess_token and then pass it to the API which returns data.

I observed that the token API is getting hit but by the time it is passed to the data API, token is `undefined`

[image]

Please suggest how to get access_token first and then pass it to data_api.

Comment: Can you please tell me you need to same logic for all API or only one API if you need to pass in all API so you can create custom hooks for a call every time before API call.

Comment: @sedhalsoni you mean I have to write a separate fetch before each api call and seprate hooks?

Comment: Yes if you need to get every time access token or the second option is to get an access token in the initial level and set it in local storage and pass it in every API call.

Comment: @sedhalsoni I have tried your way, now token and api_headers is getting printed in the console but getting `401 error`, so then I have checked in `response headers` under `Network` , observed that `auth headers is not getting injected` and hence getting `401unauthorized error`. Here is the code https://slack-files.com/T04MYU6C6-F01J7LJH6KA-7e54b04fa6. Can you please suggest a fix for this as this might be the last step to get the final result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const useFetch = (url,headers)=>{

    const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle');
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setStatus('fetching');
            const response = await fetch(
                url,headers
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data)
            setLoading(false)
            setStatus('fetched');
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, [url,headers,setStatus,setData,setLoading]);
    return { data,loading }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried out this code. but still token is coming as undefined. Not sure where its going wrong :(

Comment: my bad, I think I have to use `status` also right to check if it is idle or not?

Comment: can you please help me out here, I am a bit confused

Comment: Yes, I have tried this only but getting `token` as `undefined`

Comment: You have used useFetch twice. And api_headers cannot be used when the first useFetch answer has not yet arrived

Comment: You are using useFetch twice at the same time

Comment: ok, so in that case do i need to make a copy of useFecth and call it for getting api_data?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I do not have your complete code to tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: Hey, I have created a replica called `useFetch2`. I used `useFecth` for token and `useFetch2` for calling data api but still token is not getting passed(undefined).
https://slack-files.com/T04MYU6C6-F01HHSATB35-c70717be24
here is the complete code. can you please check once if i have done anything wrong?

Comment: You did a very good job my friend. I saw your code and solved the problem. Look at this code carefully. https://github.com/mahdi-zoraghi/fix-problem-stackoverflow/blob/main/App.js

Comment: hey, replaced ur code, getting this error `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.` https://i.imgur.com/9Wj5n57.png Not sure what that means

Comment: and btw If you dont mind, I have tried in another way. now token and api_headers is getting printed in the console but getting `401 error`, so then I have checked in response headers under Network , observed that `auth headers is not getting injected `and hence getting `401 unauthorized error`. Here is the code https://slack-files.com/T04MYU6C6-F01J7LJH6KA-7e54b04fa6. Can you please suggest a fix for this as this might be the last step to get the final result. Thanks!

Comment: ok. see this . https://github.com/mahdi-zoraghi/fix-problem-stackoverflow2/blob/main/App.js

Comment: can you join in this SFO chat please? [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226351/discussion-between-mahesh-and-mahdi-zoraghi).